# Windows 10 Taskbar open windows - thumbnails or list

Tags: windows, thumbnails, taskbar

In my old Windows 7, I could get the list of the open windows just hovering on the folder icon, and I could get the windows in "list" format:

[image]

Now, with my new Windows 10, the list of open windows has become to thumbnails.

[image]

I don't like these thumbnails, and would like to come back to see them as a list, without the thumbnails.

Is there a way to change the Windows 10 behavior?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This one isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Where do you think would be a good place fot it? I think Super User would be... I'm going to have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot turn it off completely.  You can set it to stop showing thumbnails for two or more windows though.  It requires a registry edit, and is explained here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/20989-change-taskbar-thumbnail-threshold-show-list-windows-10-a.html

The gist of it is Windows will stop showing thumbnails when there are too many, depending on screen resolution.  You can set this to be 1 in the registry so when you open more then two windows of the same program it will display the listing instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just not to leave this unanswered, i found the solution:

Add a DWORD 32 registry key in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband
```

With the name:

```
NumThumbnails
```

And the value:

```
1
```

That's all.